# Существуют ли встроенные методы загрузить json в Python dictionary?

Tags: python, json, словари

Только начинаю изучать python, поэтому вопрос возможно странный, но все же рискну задать.

Существуют ли встроенные (стандартными библиотеками) методы загрузить данные в формате json в Python dictionary? На первый взгляд их структура схожа.

Answer (score 3):

```
import json

json_dict = json.loads(json_string)
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: Я пробовал так, но так понял, что на выходе создается список.
Спасибо буду пробовать дальше, видимо я что-то не так понял.

Comment: большое спасибо, я действительно не учел, что при огромном массиве блоков json, я соответственно получу список словарей.